# Handling multiple cloned inputs in a request

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm stuck on a little issue where I can't figure out how to handle multiple cloned input fields in a single Laravel request. In a form, I have a button to clone some inputs using jQuery. So far, my HTML layout looks like this:

```
<div id="c1">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Product label & price</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::text('product_lable[]', null,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-describedby', 'basic-addon1']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::number('product_price[]', null,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-describedby', 'basic-addon1']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Licence label & price</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::text('licence_lable[]', null,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-describedby', 'basic-addon1']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::number('licence_price[]', null,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-describedby', 'basic-addon1']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-form-label">Licence duration & commission</label>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::text('licence_duration[]', null,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-describedby', 'basic-addon1']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                {!! Form::number('licence_commission[]', null,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'aria-describedby', 'basic-addon1']) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
<div id="c1_final"></div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <a href="#" class="add-clone" data-id="c1" data-to="c1_final">Add</a>
</div>
```

To clone and append new input fields in the same form, I use the following jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','a.add-clone',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let _id = $(this).data('id');
        let _to = $(this).data('to');
        let _el = $('#'+_id).clone(true);
        _el.appendTo('#'+_to);
    });
```

So far, this is working as intended. But, I run into a problem when user adds lets say 3 new input fields. When the form is submitted, I get the following response in my request:

```
  "product_lable" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Product 1"
    1 => "Product 2"
    2 => "Product 3"
  ]
  "product_price" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "2321"
  ]
  "licence_lable" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "Licence 1"
    1 => "Licence 2"
    2 => "Licence 3"
  ]
  "licence_price" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "2"
    1 => "211"
    2 => "21312"
  ]
  "licence_duration" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "150"
    1 => "151"
    2 => "555"
  ]
  "licence_commission" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "222"
    2 => "222"
  ]
```

So as you can see, for each filled out filed I get separated field name and value. My idea was to group the response with something like this:

```
  "product1" => array:3 [▼
    'product_lable' => "Product 1"
    'product_price' => 150
  ]
"product2" => array:3 [▼
    'product_lable' => "Product 1"
    'product_price' => 150
  ]
"product3" => array:3 [▼
    'product_lable' => "Product 1"
    'product_price' => 150
  ]
"licence1" => array:3 [▼
    'licence_label' => "Label 1"
    'licence_price' => "2"
    'licence_duration' => "2321"
    'licence_commission' => "2321"
  ]
"licence2" => array:3 [▼
    'licence_label' => "Label 2"
    'licence_price' => "2"
    'licence_duration' => "2321"
    'licence_commission' => "2321"
  ]
"licence3" => array:3 [▼
    'licence_label' => "Label 3"
    'licence_price' => "2"
    'licence_duration' => "2321"
    'licence_commission' => "2321"
  ]
```

So basically, I want a key=>value array, where every separate input will represent different product. I hope I described my problem clearly enough. If you need any details, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the names should be something as "product[ID][attribute_name]" where ID should be count of the existing clones (so if there are no existing it will be 0 > after that 1, 2 ,3 ...
this way at your PHP you will get $_POST['product'] array with all clones and their attributes

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will definitely try out something like this.